# Compare and replace key in JSON using python

Tags: python, json

I have a file `file1.json`

```
[
   {
      "user_id": "123",
      "provider": true,
      "username": "admin1",
      "id": "rol_123"
   },
   {
      "user_id": "234",
      "provider": true,
      "username": "admin2",
      "id": "rol_234"
   },
]
```

and a file `file2.json`:

```
[
   {
      "user_id": "12345",
      "provider": true,
      "username": "admin1",
   },
   {
      "user_id": "23456",
      "provider": true,
      "username": "admin2",
   },
]
```

I want to compare `user_id` and `username` and mark the changes in `provider` in a different file,  `file3.json` . I have a feeling we can use some kind of loop to resolve this, can someone help me out please. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried? Do you have a specific problem with your code?

Comment: probably want to first load in the json values of all files https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-load-in-python/ make your comparisons using a for loop as your elements are in a list before accessing the elements in the dictionary; make your comparisons (though this assumes that the comparisons are 1:1 and are not in a different order) and then use https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-dump-in-python/?ref=lbp make changes to the `provider` file and then dump it back to itself (rewrite with changed data).